# Simple orderBy filter not working in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a simple program to orderBy the lists by "age". But its not working and giving error! Pls help.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.min.js" ></script> 
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 
See here: <p ng-repeat="x in persons | orderby: age">{{x.name}},{{x.age}}</p>
<script>
//module declaration
var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);
//controller declaration
app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
    $scope.persons=[
        {name:"Peter",age:23},{name:"Lina",age:36},{name:"Robert",age:31}
    ];
});
</script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: what error you are getting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an error in your code. You need to use `orderBy:'-age'"`

Change your code to this and it works

```
See here: <p ng-repeat="x in persons | orderBy:'-age'">{{x.name}},{{x.age}}</p>
```

**WORKING DEMO BELOW**

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.min.js" ></script> 
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 
See here: <p ng-repeat="x in persons | orderBy:'-age'">{{x.name}},{{x.age}}</p>
<script>
//module declaration
var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);
//controller declaration
app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
    $scope.persons=[
        {name:"Peter",age:23},{name:"Lina",age:36},{name:"Robert",age:31}
    ];
});
</script> 
</body> 
</html>
```